# On Check Changed Listener For Menu Item Switch

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have a navigation drawer that contains an undetermined number of switchable items. The Nav items are added from a list of objects using a forloop. The object contains a string for the title, and a boolean to set the switch as enabled or disabled. They have to be switches no checkboxes etc...

My issues is setting an onCheckChangedListener for each item.

***My Code***

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view); 

 ArrayList<MyObject> myList; 

 for(int i = 0; i > myList.size()-1; i++){    

            MyObject item = myList.get(i);    

            String name = item.getName();    

            Boolean isDisabled = item.getDisabled();    

            navigationView.getMenu().add(name).setActionView(new Switch(this)).setChecked(isDisabled);    
}
```

**How do i then set a listener on an individual switch?***

```
 mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // do something, 
            }
          });
```

***I have tried***    //i get ClassCastException

```
   Switch mySwitch = (Switch) navigationView.getMenu().add(name).setActionView(new Switch(this)).setChecked(isDisabled);
```

Any help would be much apreciated. Thank you

Comment: Does every switch need to have the same listener? If that's the case, simply have your activity implement the `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` interface and override the method and do this `mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)`.

Comment: You may save your Switch in a field in your class. So you will be able to set the saved Switch as actionView in your Menu and will also be able to set the change listener in your saved Switch

Comment: @Vucko I tried your solution and
    onCheckedChanged method does not get called  when i change a switch. Each switch change will essentially do the same thing but I do need to be able to get the id of which switch was changed.

Comment: Well, yes. Then you need to add some logic - for example use `mySwitch.setTag(something)` and then you can maybe do something to differentiate them :/ my only idea at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for you input. I Aprecite it :) though I am unable to set a Switch variable. I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to populate your menu in this way:

```
Switch mySwitch = new Switch(this);
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...);
navigationView.getMenu().add(name).setActionView(mySwitch).setChecked(isDisabled);
```

Comment: Awsome that works. Now to impliment it with multiple switches. Thank you